# Angular Concatenate JSON result to scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, append

I have a search function that calls an external service that returns a JSON list, and i set this in scope.

I set the page number to this service, first time I send `1`, when I want to search more items I pass `2`, `3` and so on...

`result` contains the values that I expect, what I don't know is how to append to my scope the next pages.
I tried `concat` and `push` but it doesn't work.

**CONTROLLER**

```js
tantoSvagoApp.controller("ricercaAttivita", 

function ($scope, $http,  serviceRicercaAttivita) {

  function successCallBackAttivita(result) {                
    if (page > 1){
        console.log("result " + JSON.stringify(result));
        $scope.elencoAttivita.concat(result);
    }else{
        $scope.elencoAttivita = result;
    }   
  }

  serviceRicercaAttivita.getAttivita(parameters, successCallBackAttivita);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
tantoSvagoApp.controller("ricercaAttivita", function ($scope, $http,  serviceRicercaAttivita) {

function successCallBackAttivita(result) {

    if (page > 1){
        console.log("result " + JSON.stringify(result));

            $scope.elencoAttivita = $scope.elencoAttivita.concat(result);
    }else{
        $scope.elencoAttivita = result;
    }   
}

serviceRicercaAttivita.getAttivita(parameters, successCallBackAttivita);

});
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i have an error "Error: [$rootScope:inprog]"